# How to update a column via Row_Number with a different value for each row?

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-update, row-number

I have this table right now

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[DatosLegales](
    [IdCliente] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IdDatoLegal] [int] NULL,
    [Nombre] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [RFC] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [CURP] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [IMSS] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Calle] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Numero] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Colonia] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [Pais] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Estado] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [Ciudad] [varchar](50) NULL,
    [CodigoPostal] [varchar](10) NULL,
    [Telefono] [varchar](13) NULL,
    [TipoEmpresa] [varchar](20) NULL,
    [Tipo] [varchar](20) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_DatosLegales] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [IdCliente] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
)
```

I need to update the IdDatoLegal Column. Right now I have 80 rows on that table, so I need to update each row with the numbers 1, 2, 3... 79, 80.

I have tried simple queries to stored procedures with no succeed at all.

I have this stores procedure right now:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.ActualizarDatosLegales
@RowCount int 
AS 
DECLARE @Inicio int
SET @Inicio = 0
WHILE @Inicio < @@RowCount
SET @Inicio += 1;
BEGIN
UPDATE DatosLegales SET IdDatoLegal = @Inicio WHERE (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IdCliente) AS RowNum FROM DatosLegales) = @Inicio;
END
```

It returns this message when I run it

```
Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.
```

I guess that's because in the subquery (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY IdCliente) AS RowNum FROM DatosLegales) it returns 80 rows where it should only return one (but each time it should be a diferent number.

Do you know what do I have to add to the subquery to make it work? and above all, Is the loop and the rest of the procedure right?

thanks in advance

Comment: @luchosrock - The syntax, square bracket delimiters, and error message indicate SQL Server (though possibly Sybase if that has the same error messages I suppose).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can update all the rows in one statement using a CTE as below.

```
;WITH T
     AS (SELECT IdDatoLegal,
                Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY IdCliente ) AS RN
         FROM   dbo.DatosLegales)
UPDATE T
SET    IdDatoLegal = RN
```

Comment: Yes. The CTE acts something like an updatable view and it gets translated back into an update on the base table column.

Comment: That is nice to know. Also, does this update say, IdCliente = 56, IdDatoLegal = 56 (RN).?

Comment: @Kaf - It would if the `IdCliente` is seeded at 1, incremented by 1 and has no gaps as then the `ROW_NUMBER` result would be the same.

Comment: Okay,, it confused me most as it didn't have anything like `WHERE  RealTable.IdCliente = CTE.IdCliente`

Comment: +1 For the explanation and new(at least for me ;)) type of answer.

Comment: It doesn't need it as there is no join onto the CTE. The CTE defines a query and the update statement is against the CTE itself. The CTE definition is expanded out so it is basically the same as doing `UPDATE dbo.DatosLegales SET IdDatoLegal = Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY IdCliente )` (though that isn't valid syntax)

Answer (score 5):

```
UPDATE D
SET IdDatoLegal = RN 
FROM DatosLegales D JOIN 
 (
   SELECT IdCliente, Row_number() OVER (ORDER BY IdCliente) AS RN
   FROM   DatosLegales
 ) Temp
ON D.IdCliente = Temp.IdCliente
```

Comment: There is no need for a Join back onto the base table. The plan for this is less efficient as it adds the join and a spool.

Comment: Ah okay, I just asked the similar question on other way around. Your answer bit confused me.